# Mostrar consultas de forma mas optima MySql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Actualmente tengo una consulta que trabaja sobre dos tablas `egresos (expenses)` e `ingresos (incomes)`. Este es un ejemplo de como se ve la estructura de ambas tablas ya que poseen las mismas columnas:

```
|       id|        date |   amount|
|---------|-------------|---------|
|        1|  2019-02-02 |     2500|
|        2|  2019-03-16 |    4000 |
|        3|  2019-04-02 |    5430 |
```

y esta es la consulta que tengo actualmente:

```
SELECT
    t1.month,
    COALESCE(t2.amount, 0) AS expenses,
    COALESCE(t3.amount, 0) AS incomes
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM expenses
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t2
    ON t1.month = t2.month
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM incomes
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t3
    ON t1.month = t3.month
ORDER BY
    t1.month;
```

Aquí esta el hilo para ver en detalle y realizar pruebas:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/466bd69/1

La consulta retorna el monto total de ambas tablas por cada mes del año actual, esto funciona bien. Sin embargo al revisar el plan de ejecución, ya que tengo muchos registros, esta tarda demasiado por que recorre todos los registros de ambas tablas. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo optimizarla? Traté de agregar un índice al campo `date` sin ninguna mejoría. ¿Debo reestructurar mi consulta?

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir la estructura de las tablas (tipo de campos, claves, índices, etc.)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la estructura es básicamente como la descrita en la publicación, tengo otras columnas pero que no son relevantes para el caso, lo importante: el campo id auto incrementable, el campo fecha (date) y el monto, solo trate de agregar un indice normal para el campo fecha

Comment: ¿Que indices tienen estas tablas?

Comment: @Juan el indice único autoincrementable del id y al campo fecha (date) le agregue un indice normal

Comment: Podrias aclarar que indice agregaste, como lo agregaste, y cual fue el explain despues de esos indices? tene en cuenta que agregar un indice aca no va a hacer nada, ya que no hay un where para que entre por indice. Simplemente, necesita recorrer todas las filas, y eso es lento... te guste o no. Por lo tanto, no entiendo que otro tipo de ideas esperas.

Comment: Es una lástima que no hayas agregado información, como la que te había pedido gbianchi. En mi caso, me llama mucho la atención que busques una consulta por  mes de toda la historia, es efectivamente así, o en realidad es la información de una año o un ejercicio contable?

Comment: Lo único que te puedo sugerir, si efectivamente se tratase de un sistema del tipo contable, es que manejes columnas de año y mes (tipo int) con un índice compuesto por las mismas.

Comment: La idea de lo que te mencionaba antes, puedes verla aquí: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c36c5/3/0. Claramente se genera otro plan de ejecución, distinto al de tu consulta, pero deberías probarlo con datos reales y evaluar si hay alguna mejora en la performance.

Comment: Sé que esta pregunta es algo añeja, llegué aquí por casualidad hoy. Lo que puedo decir es que, dado que quieres obtener información que resume todas y cada una de las filas de la tabla, no veo cómo esperas otra cosa que no sea un _full table scan_ que hace justamente eso, visitar todas las filas. Lo que sería preocupante es que el motor hiciera varios _full scans_ y para ello probablemente vendría bien una columna y un índice por mes. Pero de un _full table scan_ no te libras por nada.

Answer (score 21):

Si tu problema es la velocidad de ejecución y, teniendo en cuenta que agrupas mensualmente por gastos e ingresos, yo te propondría crear una tabla intermedia con esos totales que podrías ir actualizando con un disparador o un evento. De esta forma, al tener el dato previamente calculado, tu consulta sería mucho más ágil.

Con respecto a tu SQL, lo veo impecable. Agrupas antes de hacer los `LEFT JOIN`, has definido el índice para el campo por el que agrupas... ¿Tal vez crear un campo `mes` para ahorrarte la función `MONTH()`? Definitivamente yo crearía la tabla de totales y la consultaría directamente. Ya se encargará de actualizarla un disparador o un evento.

Para crear la tabla la primera vez, únicamente debes anteponer a tu consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE totales AS
SELECT ... (Aquí va tu consulta)
```

A partir de ahora, con un simple `SELECT * FROM totales;` podrás ver los totales calculados sin necesidad de calcularlos nuevamente. Ya te puedes imaginar cuánto reducirás el tiempo de espera.

Y, para mantener los registros actualizados, puedes crear un disparador en las tablas `incomes` y `expenses` que llamen a un procedimiento almacenado encargado de actualizar el campo del registro al que afecten. El procedimiento almacenado Sería algo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE actualiza_expenses(v_mes int)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE total float;
    SELECT SUM(amount) INTO total
      FROM expenses WHERE MONTH(date)=v_mes;
    UPDATE totales set expenses=IFNULL(total,0) WHERE month=v_mes;
  END;
```

Que llamaríamos desde el disparador así:

```
CALL actualiza_expenses(1);
```

Ahora vamos con el disparador, que deberá activarse cada vez que se inserte, actualice o elimine algún campo de la tabla `expenses`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER expenses_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON expenses
  FOR EACH ROW
  CALL actualiza_expenses(MONTH(NEW.date));
```

Para `UPDATE` y `DELETE` es análogo, así como para la tabla `incomes`.

Para comprobar su funcionamiento:

```
INSERT INTO expenses (date, amount)
  VALUES ('2019-01-01',300);
```

Y verás como, la tabla `totales`, queda inmediatamente actualizada:

```
SELECT * FROM totales;
```

Comment: Ya me dices qué tal, quedo a tu disposición para aclarar cualquier duda.

Comment: gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder, mi duda principal es: en que momento creo la tabla de totales cual seria su estructura? perdona si no comprendí bien esa parte, gracias de antemano

Comment: La tabla de totales la creas a partir de la consulta que has hecho y tendrá la misma estructura que tu consulta.

Comment: comprendo, el problema ahora es que tengo el siguiente error al crear el SP: `Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3` sin embargo la sintaxis es correcta, alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Con qué instrucción aparece ese error? Si es al crear el procedimiento almacenado, igual es por los delimitadores

Comment: linea 3 del SP en la parte `DECLARE total float;`

Comment: Igual tu servidor no te permite crear SP... Si el problema es la variable, puedes probar a prescindir de la variable sustituyendo total por la consulta entre paréntesis, a ver qué tal...

Comment: Me sorprende y me preocupa que ésta respuesta tenga tantos votos a favor. Ese trigger va a provocar un full scan cada vez que se inserte un registro, resultando que por acelerar una consulta se va a alentar la inserción ¿Qué será mas frecuente, la consulta del balance o la inserción de ingresos/egresos?

Comment: Hola @Sal, totalmente de acuerdo contigo, de hecho a mí me ha gustado más tu respuesta. Entiendo que se haya votado más ésta porque, en cierto modo, repartes los tiempos de espera: como bien indicas, a cambio de esperar un poco más en cada inserción, obtienes el balance mucho más rápido, que era el objetivo final. Posiblemente la mejor solución consista en optimizar esos cálculos intermedios con tu aportación porque, por muchas recomendaciones que nos saltemos, ninguna consulta será más rápida que la de un dato previamente calculado.

Answer (score 9):

espero que te sirva:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(COALESCE(ee.`date`, ii.`date`), '%m') as mes,
       (
         select SUM(amount)
         from `incomes` i
         where DATE_FORMAT(i.`date`, '%m') = mes
       ) as ingresos,
       (
         select SUM(amount)
         from `expenses` e
         where DATE_FORMAT(e.`date`, '%m') = mes
       ) as gastos
from `expenses` ee
     join incomes ii on DATE_FORMAT(ee.`date`, '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(ii.`date`,
      '%m')
group by mes
```

Basicamente:

1. Cogemos las fechas que tengamos en cualquiera de las dos tablas (COALESCE) y le ponemos el alias de 'mes'.
2. Hacemos un Select sobre los ingresos (incomes), donde sea el mismo mes que 'mes'
3. Repetimos lo mismo que el paso 2, pero esta vez con los los gastos (expenses)
4. Hacemos un JOIN entre estas dos tablas, que son unidas por el 'mes' de la fecha que tiene cada registro.
5. finalmente agrupamos por 'mes'

Un saludo! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Un modo de trabajar en este caso puede ser el uso de tablas temporales, las cuales desaparecen al cerrar la sesión o bien puedes eliminarlas con un `"DROP TABLE"` tras realizar la consulta. 
En el ejemplo creo una tabla temporal para los meses del año y dos tablas temporales que reflejan el acumulado de 'incomes' y 'expenses' en undeterminado periodo, en este caso el año 2019. Una vez creadas estas tablas la consulta con `join` para mostrar los datos va a ser menos pesada porque los datos ya están filtrados.

Espero que te sirva.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `expenses` (
  `id` int(121) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX idx_date ON expenses (date);

INSERT INTO `expenses` (`date`, `amount`) VALUES
('2019-02-02', 1000),
('2019-03-16', 2400),
('2019-04-02', 1000),
('2019-05-12', 2400),
('2019-06-02', 1000),
('2019-06-12', 2400),
('2019-07-02', 1000),
('2019-08-12', 2400);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `incomes` (
  `id` int(121) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX idx_date ON incomes (date);

INSERT INTO `incomes` (`date`, `amount`) VALUES
('2019-02-02', 1000),
('2019-03-16', 2400),
('2019-04-02', 1000),
('2019-05-12', 2400),
('2019-06-02', 1000),
('2019-06-12', 2400),
('2019-07-02', 1000),
('2019-08-12', 2400);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MOY (MES INT);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
INSERT INTO MOY (MES) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE INC (
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM incomes 
    WHERE YEAR(date)=2019
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #4**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE EXP (
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM incomes
    WHERE YEAR(date)=2019
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
);
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #5**

```
SELECT M.MES, E.amount AS EXPENSES, I.amount AS INCOMES
FROM MOY M
LEFT JOIN INC I ON I.month=M.MES
LEFT JOIN EXP E ON E.month=M.MES
ORDER BY M.MES;

| MES | EXPENSES | INCOMES |
| --- | -------- | ------- |
| 1   |          |         |
| 2   | 1000     | 1000    |
| 3   | 2400     | 2400    |
| 4   | 1000     | 1000    |
| 5   | 2400     | 2400    |
| 6   | 3400     | 3400    |
| 7   | 1000     | 1000    |
| 8   | 2400     | 2400    |
| 9   |          |         |
| 10  |          |         |
| 11  |          |         |
| 12  |          |         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Agrega un índice que use la función MONTH(). (Disponible desde MySQL +8.0.13)

```
alter table expenses add index idx_expenses_month_date((MONTH(date)));
alter table ingresos add index idx_ingresos_month_date((MONTH(date)));
```

Esto debería evitar los full scan de las tablas.

[MySql dox](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts)

Answer (score 4):

Para que use el índice (en MySQL <8.0.13) evita las funciones, 
lo puedes hacer segmentando las fechas inicial y final de cada mes:

```
SELECT f.month
     , ( SELECT ifnull(sum(amount),0)
           FROM expenses
           WHERE date >= f.desde and date <= f.hasta
       ) expenses
     , ( SELECT ifnull(sum(amount),0)
           FROM incomes
           WHERE date >= f.desde and date <= f.hasta
       ) incomes
  FROM ( SELECT month
              , cast( concat_ws('-', 2019, month, 1) as date) desde
              , last_day(concat_ws('-', 2019, month, 1)) hasta
           FROM (SELECT 1 month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION
                 SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12
                ) months
       ) f
```

Tienes otras opciones antes de agregar una tabla.

1. Agregar índices; simples, compuestos, funcionales o incluso sobre otra columna llenada con un trigger.
2. Si no toma el índice naturalmente puedes considerar usar *hints*.

Es más barato agregar un índice que una columna, es más barato agregar una columna que una tabla.

Para el diseño de bases de datos tenemos básicamente dos opciones:

- El **Modelo Relacional** busca optimizar el almacenamiento de la información; hablamos del proceso de transacciones (OLTP).
- El [**Modelo Dimensional**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelado_dimensional) busca optimizar la consulta de la información, hablamos del proceso de análisis (OLAP).

El principio de *"No almacenar cálculos"* proviene implícitamente de la [Normalización de Bases de Datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos), considerando que el resultado del cálculo puede ser una *dependencia funcional*.

Las **tablas de agregación** son usadas en el Modelo Dimensional y en un contexto de uso particular: **datamarts** con *esquemas en estrella ó copo de nieve*.

Comment: me llamo mucho la atención lo que expones acerca no almacenar cálculos a través de tablas de agregación, puedes recomendarme un articulo o alguna fuente donde pueda leer mas al respecto

Answer (score 4):

En tu pregunta comentas que la consulta retorna el monto total de ambas tablas por cada mes del año actual, pero no veo que coloques ningún WHERE donde le digas que sólo te traiga los meses del año actual.  Así las cosas, te está trayendo información de todos los años y por eso es que va lenta.

¿Si le colocas los WHERE del año no mejora?:

```
SELECT
    t1.month,
    COALESCE(t2.amount, 0) AS expenses,
    COALESCE(t3.amount, 0) AS incomes
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM expenses
    WHERE YEAR(date)=2019
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t2
    ON t1.month = t2.month
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM incomes
    WHERE YEAR(date)=2019
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) t3
    ON t1.month = t3.month
ORDER BY
    t1.month;
```

Answer (score -4):

Bien si trabajas con [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) debes tener encuenta que es uno de los mas lentos para realizar consultas probablemente el problema no sean la estructura de la consulta.

sugiero considerar el uso de PostgreSQL, si ya agotaste esa opción recomiendo que uses un modelo Controlador basado en [oop](/questions/tagged/oop)+[mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) las consultas no solo las realizaras con rapidez sino que el controlador se encargara de mantener los datos para su re-utilización actualizados superando el obstáculos que presenta [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) con su lentitud Histórica insufribles en bases de datos inmensas, si eres un emprendedor que deseas desarrollar e innovar por tu cuenta con [php](/questions/tagged/php) sin ayuda de frameworks recomiendo que pases por este sitio que no tiene nada de perdida y adaptes este código a tus necesidades es bastante sencillo solo debes crear las consultas que necesitas y veras que la rapidez de tus consultas Reutilizando el código y disminuyendo las consultas al servidor.

Espero Te sirva de Mucho...
Os dejo el enlace de Victor Robles
[Victor Robles Ejemplo PHP + POO + MVC](https://victorroblesweb.es/2014/07/15/ejemplo-php-poo-mvc/)

Comment: Si hay evidencia sustentada recomiendo visite el siguiente portal(¿Porqué MySQL es lento con grandes tablas?)[http://www.tufuncion.com/optimizar_mysql] , Cabe destacar que el Usuario en cuestión indica que tiene muchos registros si este pasa el Millon estaria sacrificando Recursos que es el Principal Problema de Postgresql que consume recursos, de hecho Postgresql es lento pero efectivo tiene una mejor seguridad, en este momento es cuando se debe poner en una balanza lo que se debe sacrificar velocidad o rendimiento y compensar las carencias, Recomendar buenas practicas es una solución siempre